# Fatal error in joomla component

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.7

i just installed a new component in my site but when i click on component settings button in the backend i am getting this message:

Fatal error: Call to a member function loadByOption() on a non-object in /mysite.com/administrator/components/com_sigpro/models/settings.php on line 32

the file contains this code:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die ;



class SigProModelSettings extends SigProModel

{



    protected $extensionID = null;



    public function getForm()

    {

        $option = $this->getState('option');

        if (version_compare(JVERSION, '2.5.0', 'ge'))

        {

            $component = JComponentHelper::getComponent($option);

            $this->extensionID = $component->id;

            JForm::addFormPath(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR.'/components/'.$option);

            $form = JForm::getInstance($option.'.settings', 'config',     array('control' => 'jform'), false, '/config');

            $form->bind($component->params);

        }

        else

        {

            $component = JTable::getInstance('component');

            $component->loadByOption($option);

            $this->extensionID = $component->id;

            $form = new JParameter($component->params, JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR.DS.'components'.DS.$option.DS.'config.xml');
        }

        return $form;

    }
```

PS my site is running Joomla 1.7.5 stable version and i cant upgrade it to 2.5 because the site is online and productive some components dont works on version 2.5 .
So i will appreciate it if someone can help me fix this error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: By `com_sigpro`, I assume you're using [Simple Image Gallery PRO](http://www.joomlaworks.net/extensions/commercial-premium/simple-image-gallery-pro). This is a commercial extension, therefore you should contact the developer as it's what they're there for. This is also assuming you paid for the extension rather than torrenting it or something

Answer (score 0):

you 1.6 needs 1.6 specific modules, components & plugins. You'll need to find a 1.6 compatible version or alternative or check the permissions on /configuration.php

Comment: Well this component there isnt in version 1.6 but i know that i have to insert some code to make this run properly.

Comment: @maryam, the OP is using Joomla 1.7.5 (unfortunately), so 1.6 is completely out of the question here.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the table class is not present in your file system. It should have been there in the /mysite.com/administrator/components/com_sigpro/tables folder , somewhere ( may vary depending on the code, but looks like they have not included a custom path ). The class should extends JTable class.